# Maximum Uniqueness and Rolle's Theorem

Tags: optimization, rolles-theorem

Consider the function $y(x)=f(x)(1-x)$ where $x\in[0,1]$, $y(0)=y(1)=0$.

Knowing that $f(x)$ is continuous differentiable everywhere, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=c$ where $0<c<1$, $f'(x)>0$, can one claim that the maximum $x^* \in (0,1) $ is unique?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Absolute. I did the edit. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean local max/min? For example, when $f(x)=x^2$, $y$ has no absolute max in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but according to the Rolle's Theorem in (0,1) there is at least a stationary point, moreover since f(x) is strictly increasing any value of $x \in(0,1)$ implies y(x)>y(0)=y(1)=0. I am asking if the stationary point is unique under the condition above. If the question is not clear let me know that I can edit it again. Best

Comment: I was thinking to show that $y(x)'>0$ from $(0,x_1)$ and $y(x)'<0$ from $(x_1,1)$ where $0<x_1<1$, but the $f''(x)>0$ confused me.   Best

Comment: $y$ need not be concave. See [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x+(54.7+%2B+250+x)+%2B+125+cos(0.2+%2B+2+x)+-+125*cos(0.2))*(1-x)+for+x%3D0..1).

Comment: Yeah I see, however, I can't prove that is unique.

Comment: Wow, you have substantially changed the question. I would suggest in the future you either add it at the bottom of the question, or else ask another question.

Comment: We have

$$y'(x) = f'(x)\big(1-x\big) - f(x),$$

so $y'(x) = 0 \iff f'(x) = f(x)/(1-x)$. Now, $f(x)$ and $1/(1-x)$ are both increasing and $>0$, and hence their product also is. It follows that if $f'$ is non-increasing it can intersect $g(x):=f(x)/(1-x)$ at most once. Also, notice that because $g(0) = 0$, $\lim_{x\to1^-} g(x) = +\infty$ and $f'(0)>0$,  such an intersection **will** occur if $f'$ is non-increasing. It hence remains to consider cases in which $f'$ is not non-increasing.

Comment: My apologies for the change in the question, and thanks for your useful answer. I would add that if $f'$ is increasing and concave the intersection is unique since f'(0)>0, correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, consider $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}+x$. We got $g'(x)=\dfrac{(f')^2(x)-f'(x)f''(x)+(f'')^2(x)}{(f'')^2(x)}=\dfrac{(f'(x)-f''(x))^2+f'(x)f''(x)}{(f'')^2(x)}>0$. Then g is a increasing function. Supose that $x$ and $z$ are critical points for your $y$ function, by your relation, $\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}+x=1=\dfrac{f(z)}{f'(z)}+z$, then $g(x)=g(z)$, hence $x=z$, as you desired.

I'm wondering about your way of answering your question. How do you conclude that $f(x)/f'(x)$ is increasing? My g function is, but $g(x)-x$ is increasing?

P.S.: the derivative of g is not greater than zero. I've made a mistake on differentiation. Haha